# Retrieve local variable value in another method in java

Tags: java, methods

```
public class DemoClass {

    public void setValue(int a, int b)
    {
        int x=a;
        int y=b;
    }
    public void getValue()
    {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DemoClass dc=new DemoClass();
        dc.setValue(10, 20);
        dc.getValue();
    }
}
```

In the above program I have two methods setValue() and getValue(). SetValue method has two variables x and y which are assigned values 10 and 20(from the main method).

Now I want to display the value of x and y variables in getValue() method. But this is not possible as they are local variables. Is there any possible way of doing this?

Comment: no, you can only do it by making them class members

Comment: make them instance variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set them as public, or if you want to use getters and setters, you can do this.

```
public class DemoClass {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public void setValue(int a, int b)
    {
        this.x=a;
        this.y=b;
    }
    public void getValue()
    {
        System.out.println(this.x);
        System.out.println(this.y);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DemoClass dc=new DemoClass();
        tc.setValue(10, 20);
        tc.getValue();
    }
}
```

You can also put information in a constructor function like so:

```
public class DemoClass {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public DemoClass() {
        this.x = 0; // default value
        this.y = 0; // default value
    }
    public void setValue(int a, int b)
    {
        this.x=a;
        this.y=b;
    }
    public void getValue()
    {
        System.out.println(this.x);
        System.out.println(this.y);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DemoClass dc=new DemoClass();
        tc.setValue(10, 20);
        tc.getValue();
    }
}
```

That way, when you create the object like:

```
DemoClass demoClass = new DemoClass();
```

It will already have those objects set. If you don't do this and accidentally call getValue() and nothing is set, you will get a `nullPointerException`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any possible way of doing this?

The usual thing is to make them *fields* of the class, specifically *instance fields*:

```
public class DemoClass {

    private int x;           // These are
    private int y;           // instance fields

    public void setValue(int a, int b)
    {
        this.x = a;
        this.y = b;
    }

    public void getValue()
    {
        // Use `this.x` and `this.y` here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DemoClass dc=new DemoClass();
        dc.setValue(10, 20);
        dc.getValue();
    }
}
```

It's relatively rare to set two separate fields with a single `setValue` method, but there are use cases. Normally you'd have `setX` and `setY` (and `getX` and `getY`).